# Tengo problemas con el pip de mi Python

Tags: python, django, pip

Trato de instalar el siguiente paquete `pylint-django` desde *cmd* y me sale esto:

> C:\Users\Ariana>pip install pylint-django "pip" no se reconoce como un
> comando interno o externo,programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comenzó a suceder luego de actualizar **pip**. Alguien sabe que es y como arreglarlo?

Comment: Cuando no se reconoce el comando, es porque no se ha agregado a las variables de entorno

Comment: tienes que agregarlo al PAHT, en resumen a las variables de entorno, agregando la ruta del archivo encargado de ejecutar esa funcion

Comment: si quieres ejecutar `pip` desde cualquier lugar, agrega su ruta al path, pero diría que lo más común es moverse a la carpeta donde está `pip.exe` y ejecutar el comando desde allí. Por ejemplo, en mi PC hay un `pip.exe` en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`, que es el que se instaló con VS 2019.

Comment: Si lanzar `python` desde línea de comandos te sigue funcionando, puedes usar `python -m pip install loquesea`

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/590404/630

Answer (score 0):

Dijiste que esto sucede tras actualizar Pip, ¿cierto? Bueno, quizá te topaste con un error como:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado:  [...]
```

En ese caso, posiblemente la re-instalación de Pip falló. Windows es muy "sensible" con los permisos que le da a los programas, y puede que no haya permitido que se instalara `pip.exe`. El problema es que Pip ya eliminó su propio ejecutable, y correr el comando `pip` ya no funciona.

En la [documentación de Pip](https://pip.pypa.io), se recomienda usar `py -m pip` en vez de `pip`. Esto simplemente para llamar a la biblioteca de Python, y no precisamente al ejecutable.

Así, correr `py -m pip install pylint-django` debe funcionar. (O en su defecto, `python -m pip install pylint-django`).

---

Y, para resolver el asunto con el ejecutable de Pip, puedes correr `py -m pip install -U pip`, en una terminal con permisos administrativos.