# Por qué al usar Python y PIP, la carpeta scripts está vacía?

Tags: python, pip, instalacion

Tengo un problema al instalar la version 3.10.7 de PYTHON, ya que para trabajar y descargar librerias necesito PIP. En los tutoriales les carga todo correctamente, pero a mi no, pues en la carpeta Scripts donde debe estar PIP me la arroja vacia y por ende no puedo trabajar con este.

[image: Mi carpeta luego de la instalación]

Comment: Si verdaderamente eso está vacío, creo que habrá malfuncionamiento de otras cosas ya que son directorios de trabajo del propio sistema y programas. Si es así, sugeriría eliminar el perfil y volverlo a crear obviamente haciendo primero un backup de tus archivos personales. Finalmente instala Python en `C:\Python310` seleccionando la opciónes "Agregar a PATH" y "Para todos los usuario"

Comment: Algo que debi añadir, en funciones previas si los sube con normalidad, incluso cuando instala dice "PIP INSTALLING", pero podria tratar de hacerlo asi

Answer (score 1):

en mi caso busque en la ruta donde se encuentra la aplicacion del idle de python y puse pip. Posteriormente, me salieron los archivos en la carpeta de "~cripts"

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tienes problemas para instalar PIP en la versión 3.10.7 de Python. Una posible solución es descargar manualmente el archivo get-pip.py desde el sitio web de PIP y ejecutarlo con Python para instalar PIP.

puedes seguir estos pasos:

Abre una ventana de comandos o terminal.
Descarga el archivo get-pip.py desde el sitio web oficial de PIP ejecutando el siguiente comando: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
Ejecuta el archivo get-pip.py con Python 3.10.7 ejecutando el siguiente comando: python3 get-pip.py
Esto debería instalar PIP en tu sistema. ¿Te sirve esta información?

Answer (score 1):

`pip` es un proyecto independiente con su propio sistema de actualizaciones, por lo que es posible que no lo tengas en tu instalación de python. Afortunadamente, python incluye un módulo llamado [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) que te facilita la instalación y comprobación de `pip`, asegurando que esté accesible en las rutas de búsqueda de ejecutables.

Para instalar la última versión de `pip` basta ejecutar:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Consulta en la documentación las opciones que puedes darle en la instalación.